Why does upstream have a blank "=" value in my local git repo and how do I remove it?
`guest@abc123 abc123 % git remote -v                                                                                     
origin  git@github.cloud.xyz.com:abc123/repo.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.cloud.xyz.com:abc123/repo.git (push)
upstream        = (fetch)
upstream        = (push)
upstream        git@github.cloud.xyz.com:abc123/repo.git  (push)
guest@abc123 abc123 % git pull upstream 
fatal: '=' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`

You can see I am getting fatal: '=' does not appear to be a git repository why is that even set? How can I delete those blank upstreams?
I tried googling this but I am not finding others with this default blank upstream setting.
When I try to set git remote add upstream .... It keeps the = blank entrys and does not reference the new git upstream remote that I added.

"why is that even set?" Because of some incorrect command you gave earlier.

Try git remote remove upstream to remove the misconfigured remote. Then add it correctly without =:
git remote add upstream git@github.cloud.xyz.com:abc123/repo.git


This did not remove the blank upstream        =   values.

You can always open the .git/config file in an editor and remove the lines by hand.

@DeanChirieleison git config --edit
